# PAM permit works only when dummy suffix is added

Tags: linux, pam, alpine, google-authenticator

I am trying to use PAM to authenticate OpenVPN against 2FA (not important info). Here is my PAM configuration:

```
account required        pam_permit.so
auth    required        pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/etc/openvpn/google-authenticator/${USER} user=root forward_pass nullok debug authtok_prompt=pin
```

I have an issue in the first line (or wherever I put it). Using the line as shown causes the PAM configuration to break for some reason I don't understand:

/var/log/auth.log:

```
: No such file or directoryrary /lib/security/pam_permit.so PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_permit.so
2022-01-06 23:02:53 err openvpn(pam_google_authenticato[9]: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_permit.so
```

However, adding ANYTHING at the end of that line (even a space or any dummy text) causes my PAM configuration to work perfectly! So in other words having this `account required pam_permit.so`  (notice the space at the end), or this `account required pam_permit.so DUMMY` works!

I don't understand what is the reason. Could anyone help me to understand what is the issue here?

I am in a Docker container (**alpine** image).

One other strange behavior I observed: putting `nullok`, or `debug` flags at the end of the second line causes the configuration to become invalid, but putting them in the middle fixes the issue. What is going on? T

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out that the issue for both strange behaviors was the CRLF characters.

As soon as I used LF everything started working as expected.